# How to Parse List of Object in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I want to parse idKeys1 and get the Attribute ID(Pds AttributeId) and Attribute Value(value) from idKeys1. I am not sure what's the best way to parse it as it's a list of PDSAttribute.

```
List<PdsAttribute> idKeys1 = m_pdssmartclient.release(PersistenceEnum.COMMIT, false);
Iterator<PdsAttribute> i = idKeys1.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
                    String parse = String.valueOf(i.next());
                    System.out.println(i.next());
                      }
```

Sample Output of idKeys1 is:-

```
[Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 20000
value = 0
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = NOT_PROCESSED
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 20002
value = -1
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = NOT_PROCESSED
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 20004
value = -9223372036854775808
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = SUCCESS
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 248
value = 1906e3551370af60d5b48854fffffffe
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = NOT_PROCESSED
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 330
value = null
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = NOT_PROCESSED
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 202
value = 1906e1611370af60d5b48854ffffffff
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = SUCCESS
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 331
value = null
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = NOT_PROCESSED
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 347
value = 1906e5a11370af60d5b48854fffffffd
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = NOT_PROCESSED
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 332
value = 4fa813bc.0.1.8.9.5.0.1
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = NOT_PROCESSED
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 12
value = 1002491107
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = NOT_PROCESSED
Status message = null

, Pds Attribute: 
Pds AttributeId = 333
value = 4fa813bc.0.1.7.8.0.0.1
Attribute Status = 
Status Code = 0
Status = NOT_PROCESSED
Status message = null

]
```

Comment: What's a `PdsAttribute`?

Comment: In my code, its a custom type class. So basically I need to parse idKeys1 and the sample output of idKeys1 is given in my question.

Comment: And you're asking us how to parse your custom type? How would we know any better than you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whats wrong with

```
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            PdsAttribute attr = (PdsAttribute) (i.next());
            String attrId = String.valueOf(attr.getAttributeId);
            String attrValue = String.valueOf(attr.getValue());
        }
```

This of course, assumes you have appropriate accessors for the PdsAttributeId and value in your PdsAttribute class. If it doesn't, you should really consider adding some to encapsulate its members.

Comment: You have extra brackets on all 3 rows. Please check what you've written before posting.

Comment: yep, I had them in two, I must have accidentally added them on the second row when I meant to add them on the first.

Answer (score 0):

If `PdsAttributeId` and `value` are fields in `PdsAttribute` class and it has setter methods defined on its fields, in iteration make following changes

```
while ( i.hasNext() ) {  
    PdsAttribute pdsAttribute = ( PdsAttribute ) i.next();  
    String pdsAttributeId = String.valueOf( pdsAttribute.getPdsAttributeId() );  
    String pdsAttributeValue = String.valueOf( pdsAttribute.getValue() );  

    // now use these values as required  
} // while
```